# Laravel Grouping

Tags: laravel, eloquent, group-by

this is my first intervention, could you help me with the problem below ?

```
return Fatura::select('cao_fatura.data_emissao', 'total', 'co_usuario', 'total_imp_inc')
        ->groupBy('cao_fatura.co_cliente', 'co_usuario')
        ->whereRaw('YEAR(`data_emissao`) BETWEEN '.$request->start_year.' AND '.$request->end_year.' AND MONTH(`data_emissao`) BETWEEN '.$request->start_mth.' AND '.$request->end_mth.'')
        ->whereIn('cao_fatura.co_os', $cao_os) 
        ->leftJoin('cao_os', 'cao_fatura.co_os', 'cao_os.co_os')
    ->get();
```

This code returns the array below but i want to group by `co_usuario`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe just put the groupBy in the end :

```
return Fatura::select('cao_fatura.data_emissao', 'total', 'co_usuario', 'total_imp_inc')
    ->whereRaw('YEAR(`data_emissao`) BETWEEN '.$request->start_year.' AND '.$request->end_year.' AND MONTH(`data_emissao`) BETWEEN '.$request->start_mth.' AND '.$request->end_mth.'')
    ->whereIn('cao_fatura.co_os', $cao_os) 
    ->leftJoin('cao_os', 'cao_fatura.co_os', 'cao_os.co_os')
    ->groupBy('cao_fatura.co_cliente', 'co_usuario')
->get();
```

Here the response group by co_cliente and then co_usuario

**OR**

just :

```
->groupBy('co_usuario')
```